# Disable bluetooth by default Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.10 on an Inspiron 17-7000 laptop, and found that bluetooth activates by default on startup. I'd like to disable that behavior and have it deactivated on startup by default. Now, I've found a similar question (https://askubuntu.com/questions/67758/how-can-i-deactivate-bluetooth-on-system-startup) answered for Ubuntu 14.04, but the /etc/rc.local file that it refers to does not exist on my system -- at least, not in that location. **Is there any fix for this behavior for 16.10?**

Comment: Try [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2326395) answer.

Answer (score -1):

Add the following command to startup applications

```
sudo service bluetooth stop
```